# BroadcastReceiver fires with a delay

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have a `TimePicker` and a `Button` and I want to set an alarm when the user clicks on the `Button` at the time specified.

It gets the hour well when I click on the button but the alarm is being fired sometimes at the specified time, but not always. It is fired at the specified time less times than it does not fired. Most of the times the `BroadcastReceiver` does not fire at the specified time, it fires with a delay.

This is the code that I have right now:

**On Alarm class (code refered to the BroadcastReceiver)**

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);


alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 5, alarmIntent);
```

where `hour` and `minutes` are the hour and minutes retrieved from the `TimePicker`.

**On AlarmReceiver class**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("prove", "We enter on BroadcastReceiver");
    }
}
```

**On Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
</receiver>
```

For example, I have put a log to see what hour I was retrieving from `TimePicker` before show the log of `BroadcastReceiver`. I clicked it at `16:48` (on the `TimePicker`) and this is the result:

```
12-06 16:47:02.951 7980-7980/com.project.user.project D/prove: hour: 16:48
12-06 16:50:23.727 7980-7980/com.project.user.project D/prove: We enter on BroadcastReceiver
12-06 17:00:01.070 7980-7980/com.project.user.project D/prove: We enter on BroadcastReceiver
```

As you can see, the `BroadcastReceiver` has been fired two times at `16:50` and `17:00` when I suppose that they should fire at `16:48` and `16:53` because I have set that it will be a delay of 5 minutes between them, not 10 minutes as in this case.

So, what can I do to fire the alarm at the exact time and not fire it with a delay? Am I missing some configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), `setRepeating` is inexact.

> As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application
>   needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms,
>   rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of
>   their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact

So, to fire the alarm at the exact time as of API 19, use [`setExact`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), and inside each alarm set the next alarm.

> Schedule an alarm to be delivered precisely at the stated time.

Comment: And I have a question, if I have an alarm that should repeat two or three times at the exact time. For example, at `16:48`, `16:50` and `16:52`. Should I add three events calling `setExact` function?

Comment: If you want to set the alarms in groups of 3 and they don't have a specific pattern, then I believe you should use `setExact` three times, yes. Otherwise, if you want the alarm to trigger every 2 minutes (for example), then just use `setExact` once and reschedule in the receiver, as mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, they will have a specific pattern, for example, every 2 minutes. But I do not understand what they mean when they say `reschedule`.

Comment: `setExact` only schedules the alarm for one time. Since you need your alarm to be repeating, you will need to call `setExact` inside your `onReceive` with the next alarm's time, that's what's meant by _**reschedule**_.

Comment: So `reschedule` means something like `re-calling` the BroadcastReceiver each time?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Re-calling it using the `AlarmManager`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use **setInexactRepeating**

```
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 5, alarmIntent);
```

And you can check my code what  I did in my app.I worked perfect.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToAlarm, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

May it help..

Comment: If any other query than please tell

Comment: But I need that the alarm will be exact at the specified time. And on the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) says the following: `Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements; for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at the top of every hour.`